# How to use list comprehensions for dataframe with two or more variables in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, list-comprehension

I've dataframe `df` from excel

Is this possible in any way:

```
df["A"] = [foo(b, c) for (b, c) in (df["B"], df["C"])]
```

need to pass variables in function from different columns of dataframe

thx

Comment: Use two for clauses in your list comprehension? - [multiple variables in list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40351298/5821790)

Comment: `df["A"] = [foo(b, c) for  b, c in zip(df["B"], df["C"])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`df.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on `axis=1` (for column index) to get the corresponding values of `df["B"]` and `df["C"])` for each row for passing to `foo`, as folllow:

```
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x['B'], x['C']), axis=1)
```

This is the more idiomatic and Pandas way of achieving the task.  We commonly prefer to use Pandas functions than using list comprehension since Pandas functions can handle `NaN` values better while list comprehension often gives you error when handling `NaN` values.

Comment: thx, bro, incredible workable), 
ps: just edit

lambda x:

Comment: @КонстантинПрудников  Oh, corrected the typo now, thanks!

Comment: @SeaBean--"We commonly prefer to use df.apply() than using list comprehension"--not sure if this is correct when you consider that apply is one of the slower methods in comparison to list comprehension & zip as demonstrated by [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758)

Comment: Oh, I was probably too sleepy when answering this question so that I got multiple typos.  As you can see in my argument was that Pandas function can handle `NaN` values better.   We often see people posting questions about `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable` which were actually caused by `NaN` values not properly handled when working on a dataframe with `NaN` values.

Comment: For OP's question, it essentially is to  want to achieve the same target as [How to apply a function to two columns of Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe/) but asked in a manner of using list comprehension that was trying to access the row values of 2 columns in an incorrect way.  In order to provide a quick guide, I didn't go into details with comparing various ways for system performance.